# Determine distance to vehicle in image (Matlab, OpenCV)

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, distance, vision

I have 2 image:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRqZN.png) Initial image when I detected car.

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPdlr.jpg) IPM image when I transformed image to another plan.
[image]

I don't have any information about camera parameters.
I know the location of the car in original image and in IPM image and I wish to know how can I determinate the distance between the car and the camera. Can we assume the height of the camera is 1 m.

Exist any formula or algorithm for that?

Comment: you need to know the size of a feature at known distance if you want to calculate the distance to another object of known size. That's the only way to get a distance to an object without knowing anything about the camera.

Comment: @Piglet knowing the width of the lane could help with that, right?

Comment: I don't think that would help, since when the lane is projected in the image, the closer parts (bottom pixel rows) are going to take a lot of pixels, while the ones that are further away (higher pixel rows) are going to take less pixels. So, where in this interval are we going to measure the lenght of the lane in pixels and say " a length of N pixels will be equivalent to a length of K meters in world space"? Otherwise monocular SLAM would be a lot easier.

Comment: Actually my previous comment was not entirely correct. It is true in the case of one image. But given a video stream you can in theory use the width of the lane to deduce the scale, but this would require **I)** the SLAM algorithm to accurately reconstruct the 3d lane borders (which is harder in non-urban settings), *e.g* by constraining to the borders to the known width. **II)** a discrimination (e.g segmentation) between 3d points that are lane border points and those that not. But, this will result in an arguably complex pipeline (don't forget outlier rejection).

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it appears that you are in the monocular case, where depth/scale information is naturally unavailable. I'm afraid there is no easy way to achieve what you want. Off the top of my head, here are a few options:

1- Using neural networks. This is the least expensive option (from a material and development effort point of view.). Plus, it will work if you do not have a video stream but only single images (although I'm guessing that is not your case). If performance is not an issue, you can take more or less any convolutional neural network, and train it on depth data. Otherwise, a quick search will lead you to faster state of the art networks which you can taylor to your needs. However, databases which contain depth map ground truth are a bit scarce, and you usually have to build the depth map for your training data yourself. In that case many of the open source methods listed here at the bottom of [here](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_scene_flow.php?benchmark=stereo) come to mind. Once you have the depth maps you can train for monocular depth estimation.

2- You can use stereo cameras. Those naturally give you the depth, via for example simple triangulation.

3- You have a video stream and can use IMUs or car odometry. In that case, you can use many (multisensor) Simultaneous Localization And Mapping (SLAM) method . The litterature on the subject is rich, but IMU calibration is usually a bit nightmarish.

4- You can use a cheap GPS receiver (the ublox EVK* series come to mind). In that case, you still need to use some SLAM variant (*e.g* constrained bundle adjustment or any kalman-based method). Assuming low GPS bias (since you show only peri-urban images which are not affected by multipath) this will give you a decent approximation of the scale.

Note that methods three and four will give you an estimate of the reconstruction, so if you use sparse (*i.e* feature based) SLAM methods, you will end up having to densify the region where your car is detected (unless crude estimates are ok).